# send the request to the random pods

Tags: azure-aks, istio, kubernetes-service

looking for an idea to randomize the request routing, In our Kubernetes setup we have the request routing setup:
azure DNS and LB  =>  Istio ingress LoadBalancer (configured on 8444) for TCP ==>  Istio gw (configured on 8444) for TCP => Istio virtual service => Kubernetes service which handles the TCP packet
There is no session stickiness configured anywhere but I can still see the data being propagated to the same container for a certain time. How can send them randomly to different containers?

I tried getting the logs from the kubelet and tried adding randomness in the virtual service which failed.